# How to make an image of drive directly to a cloud backup using “dd”?

Tags: disk-image, cloud-storage

I found this command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda7 of=/dev/sdb4
```

The command makes an image of `/dev/sda7` onto `/dev/sdb4`. What I need to do is to make the image directly oncloud backup like Ubuntu One or Dropbox because I dont have enough gigabytes.

Maybe I can achieve this using a different command?

Answer (score 1):

dropbox and (i assume) ubuntu one both store files locally, and replicate them to the cloud. If you don't have enough space for the copy locally, they won't help you.

A better solution is piping the dd command over netcat to a machine that does have the sapce, then uploading it from there.

Also note that dropbox etc have (relatively) very small size limits. Amazon S3 might serve you better.

Comment: I thought about piping some uploading command but I didnt know how to and what command after the pipe will let me allow directly upload to a cloud backup.Unfortunately I cant upload from another machine.. Thats why Im asking this here.I only need at least ~15GB preferably ~28GB

Comment: try tarsnap. its backed by amazon S3. http://www.tarsnap.com/ it prolly wont be a dd like bit level backup though, more likely a file level one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dropbox you should be able to use [Dropbox Uploader](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader).

Bearing in mind that I've never used the Dropbox Uploader in such a way before, in theory, using a sub shell the command should end up something like the following:

```
./dropbox_uploader.sh upload \
  $(dd if=/dev/sda7 conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c) \
  /path2/backups/sda7.img.gz
```

*Caution*: I recommend zipping every image since it will minimize space, and therefore network throughput, time, and most importantly money.  You may also want to setup a cron job so that only *n* backups are stored, (remove the n+1 backup each time) so that you don't run out of space too.

**WARNING**: You should also setup your Dropbox client software to ignore the `/path2/backups/` directory otherwise your storage will blow-up O(n²)!!!